# Why is WebStorm not recognizing js files?

Tags: webstorm

Yesterday when I created a JavaScript file WebStorm could recognize it. But now it does not set icon to my new file, auto-complete code and not working normally.

I have reinstalled WebStorm, so there is not changes. The old files of JavaScript extension is working normally.

What can be the cause of that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the registered patterns in **Preferences | Editor | File types -> Text** file type - can you see `<your file name>.js` there? Removing this pattern from the list should help

Comment: Yeah it helped me